# How to read an azure blob line by line?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am working in containers against fairly large blobs. The data is log data and each line is several kb. I expected BlockBlobService.get_blob_to_stream to operate like a stream, but it downloads the whole thing. How can I actually stream the blob ala:

```
with some_method as blobStream:
for line in blobStream:
    <do something with line>
```

For my needs I cannot download the entire stream or hold it in memory I just need a line at a time.

Comment: Have you tried using `StringIO` to read the blobstream as a string ?

Comment: Is the content of each line has fixed number of characters?

Comment: The content is not fixed length. Unfortunately, StringIO itself doesn't help the scenario as get_blob_to_stream downloads the whole content in a single shot to the output stream. Also, it has to be BytesIO as it stands.

Answer (score 3):

As such no functionality exist that will enable you to read a blob line by line. You would need to come up with your own solution for that.

However you can certainly read partial content of the blob when using [`get_blob_to_stream`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py#L1807) method. If you see this method's signature:

```
def get_blob_to_stream(
        self, container_name, blob_name, stream, snapshot=None,
        start_range=None, end_range=None, validate_content=False,
        progress_callback=None, max_connections=2, lease_id=None,
        if_modified_since=None, if_unmodified_since=None, if_match=None,
        if_none_match=None, timeout=None):
```

You will notice that it has two parameters (`start_range` and `end_range`). These two parameters will enable you to read partial blob content instead of reading the whole blob.

What you could do is read a chunk of data (say 1MB at a time) and then build some logic to break this data by line.

Comment: That is a great possible solution, but I went another path.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up setting the blob as public and doing the following since it is text. Not super ideal but it gets the job done.

```
import urllib.request

for line in urllib.request.urlopen(blob_url):
    <do something with line>
```

*EDIT*

One problem I had to contend with was socket loss because I was working against a live blob. I had to take a snapshot and use a session or I was gettign disconnects after about 5 seconds of processing.

```
snapshotBlob = append_blob_service.snapshot_blob(container, blobName)

_params = {
    'snapshot': snapshotBlob.snapshot,
    'timeout': 20000,
}

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get(target_url, params=_params, stream=True, timeout=20000)

for line in in r.iter_lines():
    <do something with line>
```

Comment: Instead of making the blob public, you could create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) on the blob with `Read` permission and use SAS URL in your code above. That way you can keep your blob secure.

Comment: One more thing: Will this not read the entire blob which you wanted to avoid in the 1st place?

Comment: It will read all of it, but it will not read all of it into memory. It runs like an actual stream. get_blob_to_stream isn't a stream itself it just dumps all of the selected range into a stream. So with the above, I am only ever dealing with <1MB of data at a time in memory.

Comment: Also, GREAT idea on the SAS

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python hence I asked the question about reading full in memory. Its great to know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Range` or `x-ms-range` in [Get Blob Request Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) to return only the bytes of the blob in the specified range.

You could implement it by `start_range` and `end_range` parameters in the Python Storage SDK.

For example, one 1GB blob file is split into 100 requests, send 100 requests per unit time.Then download it into local file for subsequent processing. Please ensure bytes wrote with right location. But this requires the system to have 1GB of memory space for its use.

[image]

A more optimized approach is recommended that you could read the log file into memory at the same time when downloading every capacity that satisfies the `quota`.

For example, a blob is divided into 100 requests, send 5 requests per unit time. Run 20 times in order. Per 5 requests is written to memory and the following 5 requests will be sent at the same time. In this way ,system just allocates approximately `quota` of memory space.

In view of the network instability resulting in the requsts interrupt need to be rewritten in the request range of bytes, I suggest that you divide file into more parts.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Great solution. The container only has 128Mb of ram but I can have many of them.

Comment: @AnonUser ok. However, in the long run, I believe you will consider the method in my answer. And thank you for your own proposal.